# differences between remind of& remind about?

Tags: differences

My workmate says "remind sb of " is the same as "remind sb about". But I have looked up the dictionary which shows that " remind sb of "and r"emind sb about" are different. So what is the real answer?

Comment: Since you have already done some research, would you care to share that with us?

Answer (score 0):

For some sentences, they would be interchangeable, but here's a case where they wouldn't be:

> He reminds me of my Uncle Nate.

That means he resembles my uncle somehow.

> I thanked him for reminding me about Aunt Sally.

That means I'm grateful to him for bringing some topic about Aunt Sally to the forefront of my mind (for example, that we needed to take her some groceries at some point over the weekend).